# Le verbe « tracter » se substitue-t-il de plus en plus à « tirer » en langage courant ?

Tags: usage, néologismes, fréquence-utilisation, évolution-récente

L'emploi du verbe [*tracter*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tracter) (« tirer au moyen d'un véhicule ou d'un procédé mécanique ») à l'infinitif est assez récent puisque [attesté](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tracter) en 1959 chez de Gaulle (TLFi).

> Un grand nombre [de locomotives] sont d'ailleurs employées à tracter
> les trains militaires (De Gaulle, *Mém. guerre*, 1959, p. 425)

Dans une émission on parle du traîneau et des chiens qui le tirent ([*traîneau à chien*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tra%C3%AEneau_%C3%A0_chien#fr)) et une phrase commence par : « Tracté par ces champions... ». On trouve aussi au TLFi des exemples d'emplois avec des choses comme l'automobile ou le ski (*tracter une caravane avec une voiture; camion qui tracte une remorque; skieurs tractés par un téléski*).

Peut-on démontrer si en langage courant l'emploi du verbe *tracter/(être) tracté* se substitue ou non à celui du verbe *tirer* (un objet)?

Comment: Incidemment, que dit un _ngram_ ?

Comment: @Toto Mais Ac.9 est [en cours](https://dictionnaire-academie.fr/nouveautes) d'achèvement et on n'est pas rendu à « T »...

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse [voila un ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tracter%2Ctract%C3%A9%2Ctracte&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)

Answer (score 2):

En effet, c'est précisément cette notion que l'on peut relever dans des livres d'origine récente et dans les domaines des engins de jardin,  des jouets d'enfants, dans diverses activités impliquant des animaux. Il existe même au moins un cas d'usage figuré et un cas d'usage médical.

([réf. 1914](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZuK0AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA89&dq=%22tracter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrhrasnsDuAhWSHxQKHeuvD8YQ6AEwDXoECDUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22tracter%22&f=false)) Tracter un objet: C'est un peu plus difficile car il faut créer une force de tractage, contrairement au fait de pousser qui utilise ... Ajouter un sensor de type «Keyboard», le nommer «Move Backward», choisir un touche pour tracter un objet (ex: ...

([réf. 2013](https://books.google.fr/books?id=vBGJ56-IvAEC&pg=PT60&dq=%22tracter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4_MCpn8DuAhUQjRQKHV1FAmkQ6AEwAnoECE4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22tracter%22&f=false))  pour le voyage accompagné. Elle lui tend la main pour l'aider à se relever. — Viens, on continuera à bavarder dans le camion. En te rejoignant, j'ai trouvé un passage pour contourner ton bout de bois. Il saisit sa main, se laisse tracter et,

([réf.](https://www.musher-experience.com/quel-poids-peut-tirer-un-husky-quel-poids-peut-tracter-un-chien/)) Quel poids peut tirer un husky? Quel poids peut tracter un chien?

([réf.](https://www.cdiscount.com/electromenager/r-balai+ramasseur+a+tracter.html#_his_)) Balai ramasseur à tracter - 103 L -JID

([réf.](https://www.smaf-touseau.com/fr/pulverisateurs/f1-pulverisateur-a-tracter_24425)) F1 PULVERISATEUR A TRACTER

([réf.](https://www.ebay.fr/b/Jouets-a-tracter/66599/bn_60152780))Jouets à tracter

([réf.](https://www.lesechos.fr/weekend/voyages/montagne-6-activites-sans-remontees-mecaniques-1283322)) La discipline vient de Scandinavie, où les habitants avaient pris l'habitude de chausser leurs skis pour se faire tracter par des rennes, puis par

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KER0CJVjNocC&pg=PA80&dq=%22tracter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifl6f8qMDuAhUJFRQKHXmxDMoQ6AEwCHoECBwQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)) dur métier pour les chevaux destinés au halage , qui devaient tracter des charges démentielles

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=55xdAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT176&dq=%22tracter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifl6f8qMDuAhUJFRQKHXmxDMoQ6AEwE3oECDUQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)) Qu'est ce donc que cette propension féminine universelle que j'invoque et que je mets au centre de l'échange informulé et informulable ? Qu'est-ce que ce désir de mère de vouloir tracter un enfant du côté de sa propre histoire ?

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=zQBqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22tracter%22&dq=%22tracter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifl6f8qMDuAhUJFRQKHXmxDMoQ6AEwHXoECEMQAg)) Donc tout dégagement large est absolument inutile et même plutôt néfaste ; – il est plus facile de tracter une dent dont l ' apex n ' est pas encore fermé ; le déplacement en est facilité , mais le risque de coudure radiculaire en est augmenté

([réf.](https://www.musher-experience.com/entrainement-terre-sports-canins/)) Dans le cadre du mushing, les chiens pourront donc tracter le vélo, ce qui est « un premier pas » vers le mushing. La vitesse et l’effort fourni par le ou les chiens de traineau commenceront à être bien plus intense qu’en canirando ou canicross. Ils auront cet objectif de tracter et cette sensation du véhicule propulsé par leurs efforts.

Comment: Illustrations intéressantes, merci. Dans la vie de tous les jours avec les remorques et véhicules, avec les traîneaux et le ski, on dit ça couramment ? Dirait-on autant sinon plus que _tirer_ ?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Je ne sais pas ; ce que je peux dire c'est qu'il me semble que le nouvel usage soit motivé par un certain côté fonctionnel qu'a acquis ce verbe, « tirer » n'étant plus que général en signification (et bien sûr toujours utilisable et utile comme quasi synonyme). J'ai aussi pu relever la constatation que c'était un verb utilisé de plus en plus. Néanmoins, globalement, il reste [loin derrière « tirer»](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tirer%2Ctracter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctirer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctracter%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: [Récemment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tracter%2Ctract%C3%A9+avec%2Ctract%C3%A9+par%2Ctir%C3%A9+par%2Ctir%C3%A9+avec&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctracter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctract%C3%A9%20avec%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctract%C3%A9%20par%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctir%C3%A9%20par%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctir%C3%A9%20avec%3B%2Cc0) le verbe semble surpasser le participe passé de tirer + avec (tiré avec). Peut-être que ça illustre simplement la faible adéquation de cette préposition-là avec tirer. Je trouve le verbe technique et inusité, mais j'aime bien.

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe ***tracter*** se substitue parfois en effet au verbe ***tirer*** dans certaines de ses acceptations.

C'est en quelque sorte un jeu de chaises musicales avec retour au sources puisque le verbe ***tirer*** avait lui-même remplacé le verbe ***traire*** (qui ne subsiste que dans le sens spécialiser de *tirer le lait* d'une vache, une brebis, etc. où il a remplacé *moudre*), et que ce verbe ***traire*** n'était autre qu'une évolution du latin ***trahere***, dont le supin ***tractus*** a donné ***tracter***, *traction* et *tracteur*.

Le latin ***trahere*** est d'ailleurs aussi à l'origine du verbe ***traîner*** dont le sens est très proche de celui de ***tracter***.

Comment: Merci ! Le retour au plancher des vaches ! L'emploies-tu couramment ? _On va faire du camping, j'ai fait ajouter une boule à mon char pour pouvoir tracter une roulotte_ ?

Comment: Oui, je pourrais l'employer : *On va faire du camping, j'ai fait poser un attelage à ma voiture pour pouvoir tracter une caravane.* (Notre vocabulaire est un peu différent)

Comment: La bonne traction, c'est précisément l'aptitude à tirer contrairement à la propulsion qui consiste à pousser.

Comment: Oui, mais à l'évidence je confonds ça avec qqc. comme _adhérence_, comme quand on dit que ça mord dans la neige... ou je vois la conséquence ou l'application la traction comme la traction. Encore un truc idiosyncratique. C'est amplifié par le fait que le verbe ou le p.p. m'est complètement inusité excepté dans _capilotracté_ ou dans un manuel bien technique... Je n'ai jamais rencontré l'emploi sous forme de verbe ni le participe.

Comment: Tracter est un peu plus technique que tirer ici aussi. Dans la vie courante, on entendra plus souvent le deuxième.

Comment: Tirer peut aussi être considéré comme l'action initiale permettant de tracter. On tire sur la corde pour tracter une charge, mais si la charge est trop lourde et ne bouge pas, on a juste tiré sur la corde, et la charge n'a alors pas pu être tractée. On peut tirer sans tracter mais difficile de tracter sans tirer

Answer (score 2):

La différence entre les deux mots, n'existe-t-elle pas dans la durée, dans le déplacement ?
Tracter un véhicule, tracter un avion c'est tirer un objet d'un point A à un point B tandis que tirer, le mouvement est court.
On tire sur un élastique, tirer le lait d'une vache, tirer le bras.

Comment: On tire aussi au fusil ...en propulsant une balle, notion de ligne droite comme "tirer un trait"